# How to get a compile error if a JAR dependency is missing?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, jar, dependencies

I have an Android project with the following dependencies:

```
-- Android App

---> MySDK.Jar 

------> 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5'
```

This is MySDK.jar that has a dependency on commons-lang3.

I'm working on Android Studio and I'm thus using Gradle.

Here is my problem:
I have shared "MySDK.Jar" to someone and he has built his own Android App on top of it.
It works but we have seen that the compiler doesn't notice the missing dependency on 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5'. At run-time there will be a crash if the code using 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5' is called. One may not notice the problem if he doesn't call the code using this library.

I know that we can solve this issue by adding the following line to Android App build.gradle file:

```
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5'
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to get a **compile error** indicating such missing dependencies? It is indeed better to see the dependency problem at compilation time rather than at runtime.

What are the recommended good practices for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`commons-lang3` is a *transitive* dependency of `Android App`. As such, it is often not needed for compilation - there are exceptions, especially regarding multiple levels of inheritance. So at compile time you (usually) do not know whether you miss a transitive dependency that you need at runtime.

This is where Gradle comes in. Gradle can (as Maven) resolve dependencies *transitively* from a Maven repository (as MavenCentral). If you put `MySDK` into a Maven repository (like Nexus or Artifactory, which have open source versions), everyone using MySDK will automatically draw `commons-lang3` so you will not miss anything at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just adding the jar file in your project you can't warning about the missing dependencies.

To do it you have to publish the jar file in a **maven repo**.
In this way you have a pom file which describes the dependencies that gradle has to download.

Answer (score -1):

Provide a method like `MySDK.init()` int your `MySDK.jar`,call a method whe is belong to `org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5'` in the `MySDK.init()` method, then put init() into `onCreate()` of your `Application`,

Another way is，put`org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5` into `MySDK.jar`，

Hope it helps you :)